# resolving non-unique symbols between c++ wrapper libraries for fortran subroutines

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries, fortran

I am working with two sets of FORTRAN code, for example, codeA.f and codeB.f. In each set of code there are subroutines with the same name, but which perform significantly different tasks (as well as common blocks).

codeA.f:

```
     subroutine init
c do something here ...
     end
```

codeB.f:

```
     subroutine init
c do something else here ...
     end
```

I create two C++ wrappers for both routines (wrapperB is identical, but swap B for A).

wrapperA.cpp:

```
namespace codeA {
    extern "C"{void init_();}
    void init() {init_();}
}
```

wrapperA.h:

```
namespace codeA {
    init();
}
```

I then compile the two wrappers into shared libraries.

Makefile:

```
codeA.o : codeA.F
    g77 -fno-automatic -fPIC -O3 -c codeA.f -o codeA.o
wrapperA.o : wrapperA.cpp
    g++ -fPIC -c wrapperA.cpp -o wrapperA.o
libwrapperA.so : codeA.o wrapperA.o
    g++ -fPIC -shared -lg2c codeA.o wrapperA.o -o libwrapperA.so
```

Finally, I want to be able to call the two different subroutines from the same program.

main.cpp:

```
#include "wrapperA.h"
#include "wrapperB.h"
main {
  wrapperA::init();
  wrapperB::init();
}
```

The main program is linked against the two shared wrapper libraries.

Makefile:

```
main : main.cpp
    g++ main.cpp -I. -L. -lwrapperA -lwrapperB -o main
```

Everything compiles and there are no complaints. However, when the program "main" is run, the init() commands perform the same action, dictated by which of the wrapper libraries was linked against first. However, if I link against only one of the libraries, the linker complains about missing symbols.

I have two question about this:

a) Is it possible to link against two different FORTRAN routines using only namespaces or some similar method to what I am doing? If so, what am I doing wrong?

b) If a) is not possible, is it possible to resolve the conflicts by instructing the compiler to append the symbols with some unique identifier when creating the FORTRAN objects (I am using gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51))?

Thanks for any insight into this.

Answer (score 2):

Your compile commands show the use of g77, which is no longer maintained and also implies the use of a very old version of Fortran (i.e., FORTRAN 77).   You are also using an old version of gcc.  If you use gcc and gfortran of version 4.3 or higher -- preferably 4.4 or higher -- then you can use the Fortran 2003 ISO C Binding to solve your problem.  In the Fortran code you can assign externally visible names to the routines with the "bind" option of the ISO C Binding.   Just assign different "bind" names to the two routines.   Then they won't clash at the library & linker level:

In one Fortran file use

```
subroutine init (stuff...) bind (C, name="init_V1")
```

and the other file

```
subroutine init (stuff...) bind (C, name="init_V2")
```

and the routines will be visible to C, C++, the linker, etc. as init_V1 and init_V2 without clashing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!The project I am working on (in high energy particle physics) is restricted to a specific (and older) version of gcc, so using a newer version of gcc is unfortunately not an option. Also, the code base that I need to make unique is rather larger, on the order of hundreds of subroutines. I see that in gcc there is a -mmangle-cpu option which prepends all symbol names with the CPU name. Is there a gcc option which mimics this, but allows for the perpende

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this SO question, which is very similar to your problem : [Static and shared library symbol conflicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216204/static-and-shared-library-symbol-conflicts)

Basically, you have two shared libraries defining different symbols : *wrapperA::init()* and *wrapperB::init()* ; but also conflicting symbols : _init__(). So when the linker resolves, it use the first of the conflicting symbol it find.

If you remove the unneeded external visibility of _init__() in your libraries by using the techniques given in the SO question : http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Exported-Symbols-of-Shared-Libraries.html, then I think you will have solved your problem. Each *wrapper::init()* will then call internally it's proper _init__() without any conflict.